# A Blues Major Scale and A Blues Minor Scale meet at one point?

Tags: guitar, scales, blues

I am fairly new to playing the guitar now backed with some theory. I was exercising the A Blues Major scale for a while now and had some very cool insights. The latest is the assumption that the A Blues Major and the A Blues Minor meet at some point.

This is the A Blues Minor Scale in the mode of the 5th fred.

[image]

It is the same pattern as the A Blues **Major** I learned when being in the box of 2nd to 5th fred.

Is this some kind of pivot point to give me a way to switch to another scale?

Comment: Yep. It's very handy to to be able to play this shape in the fifth position for minor/blues and in the second position for a more major/country sound. Not sure what you mean by 'pivot point'. since one can just move to another scale at will.

Comment: What you've shown are Am blues and Cmaj blues notes. They're *relative* to each other, there's no pivot point here, but if you take the whole pattern *down* 3 frets, you're at the A maj blues spot. Pivot point, 'A', surprisingly!

Comment: ... and then they both go into a bar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They meet because they are the same "scale", just different modes. If you're not familiar with modes you might want to explore that. But put simply, both have the same notes they just start on different notes. For example, A natural minor (A B C D E F G) is just the aeolian mode of C major (C D E F G A B).